# Password validation triggers when it should not be triggering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Working on a password reset mechanism for users. The password length validation is triggering and I'm trying to understand why.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  ...

  def create_password_reset_token
    self.update_attributes!(password_reset_token: SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64,    password_reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  def reset_password(params)
    self.update_attributes!(params)
    self.update_attributes!(password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil)
  end

end
```

**password_resets_controller.rb**

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user
    user.create_password_reset_token
    UserMailer.password_reset_email(user).deliver 
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions!"
  else
    flash[:error] = "A user with that email address could not be found."
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token(params[:id])
  if @user
    render 'edit'
  else
    flash[:error] = "Invalid password reset code."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    flash[:error] = "Password reset has expired."
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path
  elsif @user.reset_password(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**password_resets/new.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do %>
  <%= label_tag :email %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>

  <%= submit_tag "Reset Password" %>
<% end %>
```

**password_resets/edit.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>

  <h1 class="centertext">Reset Password</h1>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Update password" %>

<% end %>
```

The error is:

```
Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

The line that throws it is inside the `create_password_reset_token` method:

```
self.update_attributes!(password_reset_token: SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64, password_reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
```

Why does the validation trigger here? I'm not doing anything with the password itself. I'm simply creating a token and a time inside the user record.

Changing the validation to say `on: :create` makes it not trigger. The problem is that then users are able to reset their password to something fewer than six characters.

**CLARIFICATION**

To be clear, the order of operations is:

1. User clicks a link saying "I forgot my password."
2. They are taken to password_reset_controller/new.html.erb. This form has one field: email address. They enter their email and submit it.
3. Controller checks to see if that user exists. If it does, it tells the model to generate a password_reset_token.
4. Controller then orders an email to be sent to the user with a URL that contains the token.
5. The user clicks the URL. If the token is valid, they are taken to edit.html.erb and they enter their new email and its confirmation.
6. The controller calls the reset_password method, which actually resets the user's password.

Currently, the validation triggers on step 2, after they enter their email and click submit.

Comment: Why your `new.html.erb` doesn't have a `password field`? How you are resetting he password without having a password field? The `validation` is called on the `password field`.So the validation is triggering because there is no `password field`.

Comment: I have an edit method on the password reset controller and a corresponding edit.html.erb. I omitted them because the validation is triggered before it even gets there.

Comment: I added them to minimize further confusion.

Comment: Are you sure the `password` which is given by the `user` is` minimum six characters`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding a Proc statement to the password validation, like so:

```
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.password_reset_token.nil? }
```

Now the validation runs both during user creation and password reset, but not during the interval when there is a password reset token set. All tests are passing.

Answer (score 0):

your create_password_reset_token is calling update_attributes which will trigger validations on every field in your User model and hence trigger the password validation as it doesn't have a current one set

you would need to either

1) Use update_attribute for those specific fields and that wouldn't trigger the validation

2) Add some password_reset field or enum to your model and set that to true when the password reset button is clicked and then do something like this in your user model

```
has_secure_password :validations => false
validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}, unless: -> { user_password_reset? }
```

3) Use the devise gem to take care of this for you

Update:

Try this

```
def create_password_reset_token
  self.update_attribute(:password_reset_token, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64)        
  self.update_attribute(:password_reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
end
```

Comment: I understand why the validation triggers. What I don't understand is why it fails. The user currently has a password that is greater than six characters. They click a link to reset it and enter their email address (so the system can send them an email with the reset token). At no point does the user have a password fewer than six characters.

Comment: so when they click the button to reset it, the password isn't getting reset to nothing at that point?

Comment: That is correct. The password is not touched until the user fills out the edit.html.erb form.

Comment: can you post the user_params that are getting passed to @user.reset_password in the update controller method, I am confused on how that is resetting the password

Comment: `params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)`

Comment: Note that the validation triggers and fails before the process gets to the reset_password method.

Comment: Made an edit to the OP with the order of operations and where it fails.

Comment: copy and paste the update I just made and see what happens and if it still fails in the same spot

Comment: The first line throws `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`.

Comment: my bad, changed colons and commas so give it another try, but I think it is relating to that issue, the password is somehow getting lost when you find the user and then run its all the validations on that line but since the password has been lost it triggers a validation error or the user you are logged in with has a less then a 6 character password and that validation line was added after you created the user

Comment: I no longer get the error, but the user can now enter a new password fewer than 6 characters...